# Shopify Carriers API assign services to countries

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Shopify experts are not able to reply this. This question is about Shopify app development. This app is regarding adding custom carrier services to show real time shipping rates.

I added (Shopify API Documentation Ref: CarrierService):

```
url: store_url."/admin/carrier_services.json"
```

Posted Data:

```
{
  "carrier_service": {
  "name": "My Carrier",
  "callback_url": "http:\/\/blablabla.com",
  "service_discovery": true
  }
}
```

Now, the carrier is created and returns quotes as well. Everything is working fine.

There is just one issue: When we add any custom carrier to the shipping zone. Either it shows invalid services list i.e. services of Shopify default USPS, FedEx, or UPS services list OR shows:

There are no available services for the country you have selected
Grammatically, there is no any way to add carriers to shipping zones. I am wondering: how Shopify decides what to show? This services list is also added in shipping zones, which is read only according to API.

Logically, it should either get services while creating a new carrier and show them, OR simply show any message which represents that custom carrier services will be available.

Invalid services from Shopify default carriers:
[Invalid services from Shopify default carriers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A2ZA.jpg)

No services & wrong message:
[No services & wrong message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Wbl.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a static response on carrier service url (in this case "http://blablabla.com") it will set services automatically. Once they are visible in shipping zones then you can make them dynamic.

Comment: Its preferred to use https instead of http